# Insert zeros into vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, insert

How do I insert 3 zeros in vector `a`:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

such that vector v is obtained:

```
v = [1 2 3 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 7 8 9]
```

it should be automated such that it can be implemented in a vector with length `n`.

Comment: PLease  show what you've tried

Comment: Do you always want 3 numbers and then 3 zeros (or more to the point, the same number of zeros as non-zeros in the pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `v` does not exist and `numel(a)` is a multiple of `n`:

```
a = 1:9;
n = 3;
v(bsxfun(@plus, (1:n)', 0:2*n:(numel(a)-n)*2)) = a
```